# how do we specify our own column type value for database columns

Tags: mysql, postgresql-9.1

I want to define values for two more data types for prepared statement other than below values. For other datatypes it was showing columntype 1111. By that we can't distinguish data types

```
-7 BIT
-6 TINYINT
-5 BIGINT
-4 LONGVARBINARY 
-3 VARBINARY
-2 BINARY
-1 LONGVARCHAR
0 NULL
1 CHAR
2 NUMERIC
3 DECIMAL
4 INTEGER
5 SMALLINT
6 FLOAT
7 REAL
8 DOUBLE
12 VARCHAR
91 DATE
92 TIME
93 TIMESTAMP
1111 OTHER
```

Comment: json, uuid and so on

Comment: why not use varchar?

Comment: I think new  column types only make sense, if they have a meaning inside PostGre. But that wouldn't be so without additional functionality in PostGre itself. If you want to have a meaning to it, this should go into your business logic and is a programming task and not a database task

Comment: i work it as a programming task, but i was asking that it as any other alternative to check column type by its value